# navigateTo : New record

Tags: lightning-aura-components, navigation, save-and-new, lightning-data-service

I have replaced the standard "New" functionality on a custom object, and I want to navigate to the newly created record after save. I have [looked at the developer documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToSObject.htm), and I get that I need to just pass the correct information into the variable. But every time I add code with the saveRecord() method, I get this error: `Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [result is not defined]`

At this point, I was trying to get the new ID and pass that variable to a helper which would navigate me to the new record. Here is the code I have:

```
component.find("inventionRecordCreator").saveRecord(function(saveResult) {
    if (saveResult.state === "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state === "DRAFT") {
        //record is saved successfully
        var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        resultsToast.setParams({
            "title": "Saved",
            "message": "The record was saved."
        });
        resultsToast.fire();

        //Great, the record is saved. Lets try to navigate to it now
        var recId = result.recordId;
        console.log("The new recordId: " + recId);
        helper.navigateTo(component, recId);
```

And here is the helper code:

```
navigateTo : function(component, recId){
    var navEvt = $A.get("e.forece:navigatetoSObject");
    navEvt.setParams({
        "recordId": recId
    });
    navEvt.fire();
}
```

Edit: I was asked to post the entire controller:

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

    //Prepare new record from template

    component.find("inventionRecordCreator").getNewRecord(
    "Invention__c", // sObject Type (entityAPIName)
        "0121D0000000ZbT", //recordTypeID
        false, //skip cache?
        $A.getCallback(function() {
            var rec = component.get("v.newInvention");
            var error = component.get("v.newInventionError");
            if(error || (rec === null)) {
                console.log("Error initializing record template: " + error);
            }else{
                console.log("Record template initialized: " + rec.sobjectType);
            }
        })
    );

}, //don't forget the comma if you have more stuff

handleSaveInvention: function(component, event, helper) {
    if(helper.validateInventionForm(component)) {

        //Name will be set by APEX class Invention
        component.set("v.simpleInvention.Name", ''); 

        //Campus is selected from the picklist, so we set it in the field set
        console.log("campus__c = " + component.find('invCampus').get("v.value"));
        component.set("v.simpleInvention.Campus__c", component.find('invCampus').get("v.value"));

        //Working Title should have been already set with lightning input
        console.log("Working Title = " + component.get("v.simpleInvention.Working_Title__c"));

        //Lead Researcher was part of the lookup, so we need to set it
        console.log("Lead Researcher = " + component.get("v.selectedContactLookupRecord.Id"));
        component.set("v.simpleInvention.Lead_Inventor__c", component.get("v.selectedContactLookupRecord.Id"));

        //Now we try to save
        component.find("inventionRecordCreator").saveRecord(function(saveResult) {
            if (saveResult.state === "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state === "DRAFT") {
                //record is saved successfully
                var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                resultsToast.setParams({
                    "title": "Saved",
                    "message": "The record was saved."
                });
                resultsToast.fire();

                //Great, the record is saved. Lets try to navigate to it now
                //console.log("Let's find the result? " + saveResult.getResponse());
                console.log("Let's find the result? " + JSON.stringify(saveResult.getResponse()));

                //var recId = result.recordId;
                //console.log("The new recordId: " + recId);
                //helper.navigateTo(component, recId);
            } else if(saveResult.state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                //handle incomplete state
                console.log("User is offline, device doesn't support drafts.")
            } else if(saveResult.state === "ERROR") {
                //handle the error state
                console.log('Problem saving contact, error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
            } else {
                console.log('Unknown problem, state: ' + saveResult.state + ', error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
            }                
        });
    }
}
```

})

Comment: There is nothing like `result` we are getting all output in `saveResult` so do `console.log(saveResult);` to check this variable value and check the structure of this what it contains and here look for the `recordId` and use that for redirection. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Or do this `result = saveResult.getResponse();` and then do `console.log(result)` and look for record id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var recId = result.recordId;
```

result is not defined?

you must declare your result variable:

```
var result = something.
```

So, I am guessing you should get the response as follows:

```
var result = saveResult.getResponse().SOMETHING;
```

After updating your post, the server response is actually in your saveResult variable, in order to fetch the recordId from it, just need to do :

```
saveResult.recordId
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70633/discussion-between-chance-and-glls).

Answer (score 2):

If you assign the `force:recordData` `recordId` attribute, you can use code like the following in your callback:

```
var recId = component.get("v.recordId");
```

Likewise, the following should also work:

```
var recId = component.find("inventionRecordCreator").get("v.recordId");
```

Comment: Isn't v.recordId left blank for new records, though?

Comment: @Chance the record Id should be set after saving. I don't have a chance to test it right now.

Answer (score 0):

In your code check the spelling of e.force $A.get("e.forece:navigatetoSObject");

Correct the spelling and it will work

forece:navigatetoSObject should be as force:navigateToSObject
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToSObject/documentation

Comment: That looks like a *different* issue than the one causing this problem, but your correction is also misspelled.

Comment: Updated it after your comments